# Multinomial & Covariances

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Assume we have $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_k) \sim Multinomial(n,\mathbf{p}=(p_1,\ldots, p_k)).$

How can we find $\operatorname{Cov}(e^{X_i},e^{X_j})$?

Tried to do CLT but it's led me nowhere.

Answer (score 7):

The moment generating function is

$$\begin{aligned}
\phi(t_1,\ldots, t_k) &= E\left[\exp\left(t_1 X_1 + \cdots + t_k X_k\right)\right]\\
&= \sum_\mathbf{x} \binom{n}{\mathbf x} (p_1 e^{t_1 x_1})\cdots (p_k e^{t_k x_k}) \\
&=\left(p_1 e^{t_1x_1} + \cdots + p_k e^{t_k x_k}\right)^n.
\end{aligned}$$

The covariance for $i=1,$ $j=2$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(e^{X_1},e^{X_2}) &= E\left[e^{X_1}e^{X_2}\right] - E\left[e^{X_1}\right]E\left[e^{X_2}\right] \\
&=\phi(1,1,0,\ldots,0) - \phi(1,0,\ldots,0)\,\phi(0,1,0,\ldots,0)\\
&= \left(1 + (p_1+p_2)(e-1)\right)^n - \left(1 + p_1(e-1)\right)^n\,\left(1 + p_2(e-1)\right)^n.
\end{aligned}
$$

For the general formula, replace "$1$" by "$i$" and "$2$" by "$j$" in the subscripts.